# Counting Syllables in word, problem with .endwith function

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
numSyllables(Well):
word = Well.lower()
Syllable = 0
vowels = "aeiouy"

Sy=(len(Well))
if Sy <=3:
    Syllable+= 1
for index in range(1,len(Well)):
    if Well[index] in vowels and Well[index-1] not in vowels:
        Syllable+=1

        if Well.endwith ("es") and Well.endwith("ed"):
            Syllable -=1
        elif Well.endwith ("des") and Well.endwith("tes") and Well.endwith("ded") and Well.endwith("ted"):
            Syllable +=1
        elif Well.endswith ("e"):
            Syllable -=1
if Syllable == 0:
    Syllable +=1

return Syllable
```

I am trying to count the syllables in a word, if the syllable has less than 3 letter then it has one syllable, if there is consecutive vowels next to each other it is consider one syllable, Word endings of –es or –ed are ignored, unless it is preceded by a ‘d’ or a ‘t’. (e.g.”cares” and “harmed” are one syllable, but “carded” and “stated” are two)
Words that end in with an ‘e’ are typically silent (not counted); unless it ends in ‘le’ (e.g. “kite” and ”mode” are one syllable, but “little” and “kibble: are two)

When ever I run my code this is the result:
"/Users/andyz./Documents/Well/RScores.py", line 36, in numSyllables
    if Well.endwith ("es") and Well.endwith("ed"):
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'endwith'.

Is there a way to solve the problem that I am having?

Comment: You probably intended `endswith`: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.endswith

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it should be **[endswith](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.endswith)** not **endwith**

```
if Well[index].endswith ("es") and Well[index].endswith("ed"):
```